# Changed "&amp%3B" to "&"

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, query-string

I get an output URL like this:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/cari?q=query&amp%3Bprovince=13&page=1

How do I change **"&amp%3B"** to just **"&"**? The output URL I want is like this:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/cari?q=query&province=13&page=1

What should I change in the following code:

```
var jQuery_1_8_2 = jQuery.noConflict();
$(function () {
    var array = JSON.parse('{!! !empty($total_search_query) ? json_encode($total_search_query) : "[]" !!}');
    console.log(array);
    $('#map2').vectorMap({
        map: 'indonesia-adm1_merc',
        backgroundColor: '#ADF3F0',
        regionStyle: {
            initial: {
                fill: '#FFFFFF'
            },
            hover: {
                fill: '#175083'
            }
        },
        zoomButtons: false,
        zoomOnScroll: false,
        zoomOnClick: false,
        zoomMax: 1,
        normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
        onRegionClick: function (event, code) {
            var url = '{{ route("search", ["q" => request()->get("q"), "province" => ":id"]) }}';
            url = url.replace("%3Aid", code.toLowerCase());
            window.location.href = url;
        },
        onRegionTipShow: function (event, label, code) {
            var map = $('#map2').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
            var regionName = map.getRegionName(code);
            var a = array.find(a => a.name === myTrim(regionName))['count'];
            
            label.html('<div class="map-tooltip"><h4 class="header">' + regionName + '</h4><p class="description">Total: ' + a + '</p></div>');
        }
    });
}(jQuery_1_8_2));
```

Comment: You already have `url = url.replace("%3Aid", code.toLowerCase());` so why not add it there?

Comment: @mplungjan how? I've added it, but it doesn't work. `&amp%3B` is still exist.

Comment: `decodeURI` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI

Comment: @freedomn-m it doesn't work.